# R , Replicating the rownames in data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a **data.frame** with **dimension** [6587   37] and the **rownames** must repeat after every 18 rows. How i can do this in Rstudio.

Comment: data.frame rownames must be unique.

Comment: @jimmyb, i have to give unique rownames up to 18 rows and it continue up to 6587 rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your 18 column names are:

```
mynames <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s")
```

You can get what you want with:

```
paste0(rep(mynames,length.out=6587),rep(1:366,each=18,length.out=6587))
```

Or you can modify the names pasting different things.

Comment: @ Juanjo!     how we can extract targeted grid data from the bulk of data set? (e.g) I have to pull the certain longitude and latitude daily data from the 40 years whole region data set.

Comment: @irfan I don't understand the question. I think you should open a new question and explain it in detail.

Comment: here is the question in detail http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37385832/how-to-subset-the-randomly-repeating-x-and-y-address-with-values                                                                            And i have to export each (x,y) pair vales in separate file.

Answer (score 1):

Row names in data.frames have to be unique.

```
> df <- data.frame(x = 1:2)
> rownames(df) <- c("a", "a")
Error in `row.names<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, value = value) : 
  duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed
In addition: Warning message:
non-unique value when setting 'row.names': ‘a’
```

You could use `make.names` to make the names unique, but still carry some repeating information.

```
> make.names(c("a","a"), unique = TRUE)
[1] "a"   "a.1"
```

These could be identified with help from `grep`
Or you could make a column in df or a second data.frame that holds the information